# TracingFilter deprecated in spring cloud sleuth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

It seems that TracingFilter has been deprecated in Spring Cloud Sleuth and I could not find any alternative to inject in mockMvc like:

```
    @Autowired
    private TracingFilter traceFilter;

    @BeforeAll
    void init() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).apply(springSecurity())
                .addFilters(this.traceFilter)
                .build();
    }
```

Anyone did find any alternative ?

Jonathan.

Comment: [`TracingFilter`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/main/spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/servlet/TracingFilter.java) is not deprecated.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was! After upgrading I started to get this errors


`No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.servlet.TracingFilter' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Answer (score 1):

[`TracingFilter`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/main/spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/servlet/TracingFilter.java) is not deprecated.

The issue you see:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.servlet.TracingFilter'
```

happens because Sleuth does not create a `TracingFilter` bean (`TracingFilter` is a `Filter` and registering it in the right order can be tricky).

It is created in [`TraceWebServletConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/main/spring-cloud-sleuth-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/instrument/web/TraceWebServletConfiguration.java). You can do something similar here too though I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! I was actually trying to register a TracingFilter in my MockMvc in order to test the traceId in the response. In the old version it was easily done, but I did not succeed to implement it in the new spring cloud version!

Answer (score 1):

solved using:

```
protected static TracingFilter tracingFilter(final WebApplicationContext context) {
    return TracingFilter.create(context.getBean(CurrentTraceContext.class), context.getBean(HttpServerHandler.class));
}
```